# Is this paragraph grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I am not sure that word 'Automated' is a correct choice for the following:

> XYZ is now configured for Automated deployment by Jenkins on the QA environment. That is on a single click of button Jenkins will deploy the latest code on QA server.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Why do you feel "automated" might not be correct? Do you really mean grammatically correct, or just that a different word might be better? Please see "How do I check my text?" in the [Help pages](/help/on-topic) for pointers for this sort of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"XYZ is now configured for **a**utomated deployment by Jenkins **to** the QA environment."*

Automated is the correct word though.

**Edit**: Distinction. If the Jenkins builds were actually on the QA server you could say **on**. But they are not (obviously). Therefore the build is being deployed from dev, or a build server (if you are doing it right), **to** QA. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also "_single click **a** of button_" and "_latest code on **the** QA server._". And there should probably be a comma after "_That is**,**_".

Answer (score 0):

That is on a single click of button Jenkins will deploy the latest code on QA server.

might read better as

"That is, on a single click of a button Jenkins can deploy the latest code onto the QA server."

or

"With a single click, Jenkins can deploy the latest code onto the QA server"